# Attaching to an remote overlay network using docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I have a Docker swarm with 3 machines: 1 manager and 2 workers (all physically distinct machine running Linux). I am trying to use an overlay network to deploy an application (Dremio) as a worker on one of the manager nodes.

Since I have some node-specific configurations (via bind-mounted files), my preference would be to use `docker compose` to deploy the worker directly on the manager node rather than use `docker stack deploy`.

I have created an attachable network on the manager using:

```
docker network create -d overlay --attachable --scope swarm css_attachable
```

Then I'm able to run a Dremio container on the manager via `docker compose` and having the containers connect to `css_attachable`.

However, when I go to deploy the Dremio executor container on one of the worker nodes, it cannot connect to the network `css_attachable`. Following the Docker overlay network I can attach a single container on the worker node to the manager's overlay network using `docker run` but **not using** `docker compose`. In fact, after running the example:

```
docker run -dit --name alpine2 --network css_attachable alpine
```

the network `css_attachable` is actually listed on the worker node when I run `docker network ls`, but even after the network `css_attachable` is listed on the worker node, it still cannot be used by `docker compose` on that node. Here is the `docker-compose.yml` I am using:

```
version: "3"
services:
  executor:
    image: dremio/dremio-oss:24.3.0
    volumes:
      - dremio_executor_1_v24_data:/opt/dremio/data
      - ./core-site.xml:/opt/dremio/conf/core-site.xml
      - ./dremio.conf:/opt/dremio/conf/dremio.conf
    ports:
      - "9047:9047"
      - "31010:31010"
      - "32010:32010"
      - "45678:45678"
      - "2181:2181"
    networks:
      - css_attachable
    hostname: dremio-executor-1

volumes:
  dremio_executor_1_v24_data:
    external: true

networks:
  public:
    external:
      name: css_attachable
```

As with the alpine example, I am successfully able to connect to the network `css_attachable` from my worker with `docker run`:

```
docker run --name=dremio-executor -d --net=css_attachable -p 9047:9047 -p 31010:31010 -p 32010:32010 -p 45678:45678 -p 2181:2181 -v dremio_executor_1_v24_data:/opt/dremio/data -v ./dremio.conf:/opt/dremio/conf/dremio.conf -v ./core-site.xml:/opt/dremio/conf/core-site.xml dremio/dremio-oss
```

Is there any way to use this remote overlay network locally within docker compose?
I'm thinking of something that instructs docker to reference a remote host's overlay network - is this possible?

Thanks!

Eric

Comment: You should include the compose file, error messages, and output from various debugging commands. See [mcve].

Comment: Thanks - I added the docker-compose.yml to the post.

Comment: Also recommend cross posting at https://community.dremio.com where a lot of Dremio trouble shooting occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Typically I recommend against attachable overlay networks. There are some gotchas, including one I remember from long ago where the docker engine would try to start the container before the network was available on a restart, and fail to restart a persistent container. If you're going down that path anyway, do a lot of testing. [Placement preferences](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#placement) can be used to deploy a swarm service to specific nodes.

With that disclaimer out of the way, I think you are encountering a [known bug](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/10588) that was fixed in [#10591](https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/10591) and released in [v2.19.0](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/tag/v2.19.0). So if you are seeing this issue on an older release (check your version with `docker compose version`), it's time to upgrade.

The other issue I'm seeing is you call the network `public` in:

```yaml
networks:
  public:
    external:
      name: css_attachable
```

You need to use that `public` name in the services, not the `css_attachable` value, e.g.:

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  executor:
    image: dremio/dremio-oss:24.3.0
# ...
    networks:
      - public
# ...

networks:
  public:
    name: css_attachable
    external: true
```

Comment: Thanks, this is extremely helpful! I got a warning:
WARN[0000] network public: network.external.name is deprecated. Please set network.name with external: true

Comment: I've been thinking about trying to use docker stack deploy but haven't yet worked out how to make the bind-mounted config files appear in the right place on each node without so much fragile manual file placement.

I'm hoping to run a local registry service and push the files into some sort of registry entry but haven't had time to research it yet.

Thanks again!